# Extract JSON in table to rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

Is it possible to extract the JSON from the table into rows?
For example this is my table:

[Table with JSON in rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL2rn.png)

This is the scrip:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[json_test](
    [Lines] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [StoreCode] [varchar](50) NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[json_test] ([Lines], [StoreCode]) VALUES (N'[{"ItemBarcode":57943,"ItemQty":5,"QtyMea":"PCE"},{"ItemBarcode":58087,"ItemQty":2,"QtyMea":"PCE"},{"ItemBarcode":871042,"ItemQty":2,"QtyMea":"PCE"},{"ItemBarcode":1042801,"ItemQty":2,"QtyMea":"PCE"}]
', N'1')
INSERT [dbo].[json_test] ([Lines], [StoreCode]) VALUES (N'{"ItemBarcode":8710428017024,"ItemQty":1,"QtyMea":"PCE"}', N'2')
INSERT [dbo].[json_test] ([Lines], [StoreCode]) VALUES (N'{"ItemBarcode":5391523058070,"ItemQty":2,"QtyMea":"PCE"}', N'3')
INSERT [dbo].[json_test] ([Lines], [StoreCode]) VALUES (N'[{"ItemBarcode":6377,"ItemQty":2,"QtyMea":"PCE"},{"ItemBarcode":6384,"ItemQty":3,"QtyMea":"PCE"}]', N'4')
```

if I try :

```
SELECT  JSON_value([Lines],'$.ItemBarcode')as barcode,
        JSON_value([Lines],'$.ItemQty') as itemqty,
        JSON_value([Lines],'$.QtyMea') as qtym,
        [Lines]
      ,[StoreCode]
  FROM [json_test]
```

It will get only the first value where the JSON have an array ([]), it is ok for only one object in row{}.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cddds.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use OPENJSON... :

```
SELECT *
FROM   [dbo].[json_test]
       CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Lines)
```

And then you can do everything you want !

Comment: Please click up to say that is a solution for you for my answer !